# Problem with recieving ActiveMQ messages in JBoss (low message per second count)

Tags: jboss, activemq-classic, message-driven-bean, consumer

I'm using a remote ActiveMQ server and Message driven Beans (4 different beans) to consume the messages.

In theory the message consumption should be fast (and was fast in the past). Currently the jboss consumes a very slow number of messages (4 or so) every 4 seconds. The connection panel in the AMQ Webinterface shows two connections from my jboss consumer.

Does anybody have an idea what happens that makes my consumer so slow?

EDIT: the consumer becomes slow over time and is considerably faster after a restart. strange.

Comment: you should try another container to help narrow it down...like Tomcat in this post...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682019/starting-activemq-message-listener-in-tomcat

Comment: what is your consumer doing with the message?  try consuming it and just logging it (quick ACK back to broker) to see if that speeds things up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was caused by the database. after a lot of debugging we figured out that there was a DB backup with a very eratic shedule that made our db server so slow the message throughput dropped to nearly zero.